# How to remove file path strings from static lib generated with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static, strip

I use visual studio 2010 to create a static library in release mode.
The generated .lib file contains the paths of the source files, alog with the names of some static constants.
How can I remove all these unwanted strings?

Comment: Don't distribute .lib files if you don't want to expose these details, use a DLL instead.

Comment: Hans, thanks, but this doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: Never mistake a comment for an answer.  You get comments when you ask for a pony.